# Как включить полосу zoom в google map api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api, google-maps

Подскажите, как включить этот элемент управления:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

scaleControl: true - не показывает ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scaleControl` - это не то, что Вам нужно. `scaleControl` - это бар масштаба справа от надписи "Картографические данные". То, о чем Вы спрашиваете - `zoomControl`, а точнее его тип `LARGE`. Раньше можно было задать его так:

```
function init() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP,
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
        },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

На данный момент стиль `LARGE` нельзя установить, сейчас доступен только параметр `position`.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#ZoomControlOptions